# mysql query returning all data even though where is not satisfied LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just noticed that my `where status = blocked` is not being considered.
The query is still returning blocked and active status.

```
$contacts = DB::table('contacts')
        ->where('uid_by', $me)
        ->orWhere('uid_to', $me)
        ->where('status', 'blocked')
        ->select(
                DB::raw("IF(uid_by = $me, uid_to, uid_by) AS user_id")
        )
        ->get();
```

What could be wrong with the query?

I tried logging the query being executed:

```
{"query":"select IF(uid_by = 3, uid_to, uid_by) AS user_id from `contacts` where `uid_by` = ? or `uid_to` = ? and `status` = ?","bindings":[3,3,"blocked"],"time":0}
```

used:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
return $last_query = end($queries);
```

Comment: Does this work ? --< where('status', '=', 'blocked')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching the where statements, like this:

```
$contacts = DB::table('contacts')
    ->where('uid_by', $me)
    ->where('status', 'blocked')
    ->orWhere('uid_to', $me)
    ->select(
        DB::raw("IF(uid_by = $me, uid_to, uid_by) AS user_id")
    )->get();
```

What is happening is that is not evaluating what's after the `OR` keyword, hence, showing all blocked and active...

Comment: Is this bug still in Laravel core?